# How to extract google translated text from google translate website using jsoup in android

Tags: javascript, android, web-crawler, jsoup

I am using jsoup to retrieve data from webpage in android.
Here I am using this URL "https://translate.google.com/#hi/en/bharat%20mera%20desh%20hai" to translate "bharat mera dekh hai " to "India is my country".
I want to get English translated text as output but I am unable to get this.

here is my code for extracting English text:

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements englishText = document.select("span#result_box");
                EngText =englishText.text() ;
               } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This is HTML contents:

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">
     <span class="" contenteditable="false" tabindex="-1">
            India is my country
     </span>
</span>
```

but I am getting empty string value in EngText variable.
However I am able to retrieve other static text from website but unable to get English translated text.

Comment: Why use jsoup when you can use google-translate api? https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Comment: @waqaslam Google API is paid now. My problem is I am not able to get that English text

Answer (score 0):

The value you are trying to get is not part of initial html, but is set by javascript after page is loaded. You can check it by disabling javascript in your browser.

Jsoup only gets static html, does not execute javascript code.

To get what you want you should consider using tool like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: can you please suggest me witch one is better and compatible with android.

Comment: I am not Android specialist. You have to make your own research or use softwarerecs.stackexchange.com